# Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I need to solve this integral $$\int _0^1\:\int _{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\:\int _{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^1\:dzdydx$$ using spherical coordinates (I already made a sketch of the volume).

The problem is that I do not know my bounds for my integral in the spherical coordinates

I got

$$\int _0^{\pi }\:\int _{-\frac{\pi \:}{2}}^{\frac{\pi \:}{4}}\:\int _?^?\:r^2cos\delta \:drd\delta \:d\theta.$$

for my integral, I'm not really sure how to get my bounds for r.

Comment: Prefer cylindric coordinates. The result is half the [volume of a cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone#Right_circular_cone).

Comment: Think about rays that come from the origin (which is what integrals $dr$ do). Do they ever intersect the cone? (No). Next, what would the equation of the plane $z=1$ be in spherical coordinates?

Comment: I made some interpreting mistakes, the first bounds should be from $-\frac{\pi }{2}$ to $\frac{\pi }{2}$ and for $\delta$ from $\frac{\pi }{4}$ to $\frac{\pi }{2}$ and then for $r$ from $0$ to $\frac{1}{sin\delta \:}$, would this be correct?

Comment: @NinadMunshi that would be $rsin\delta\:=1$

Comment: Yes exactly, so the upper bound would be $r = \frac{1}{\sin \delta} = \csc \delta$

Comment: Okay thank you!